# Do we want small caps?

Tags: feature-request

after writing this answer [What chemicals are present in burnt toast?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/827/what-chemicals-are-present-in-burnt-toast/869#comment1549_869) i have encountered that there is no small caps available in MathJax. Wouldn't it be a good idea to provide small caps  for citing s.o.?

Or is it possible to format parts in small caps through html maybe?

**Update** it seems possible to fake small caps thru using `T\scriptsize EST` which renders to  $\mathrm{T\scriptsize EST}$ . But this is somehow poor since font weight and tracking does not fit together.

Comment: Good idea.  I was going to see what Manish (one of the other mods) had to say about it later, but this works too!  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`\text` overrides all LaTeX commands inside it, so there's little use in that for upright text. Use `\mathrm` instead (unfortunately you have to include `\:` or `~` space literals). Then use the [text size commands](http://www.forkosh.com/latex/ltx-178.html), nearly all work in mathjax.

> `$NORMAL\:CAPS \:\:\mathrm{UPRIGHT \:CAPS \:\:\small SMALL\: CAPS1\:\:\scriptsize SMALL\: CAPS2\:\:\tiny SMALL\: CAPS3\:\:}$ Normal text`

$NORMAL\:CAPS \:\:\mathrm{UPRIGHT \:CAPS \:\:\small SMALL\: CAPS1\:\:\scriptsize SMALL\: CAPS2\:\:\tiny SMALL\: CAPS3\:\:}$ Normal text

So, your bread answer would use `\mathrm{\scriptsize MONNIER}` ($\mathrm{\scriptsize MONNIER}$) or `\mathrm{\small MONNIER}` ($\mathrm{\small MONNIER}$) or `\mathrm{\tiny MONNIER}` ($\mathrm{\tiny MONNIER}$)

I'm afraid Mathjax doesn't have a direct smallcaps command (off the top of my head)

Comment: Those are not samll caps those are just capital letters. Small caps would look like  $\mathrm{T\small EXT}$ were minuscule are transformed in small majuscule and majuscuel in a slightly bigger majuscuel. Just using upper case letter is typographically mhhm let's say poor `;)`

Comment: @blood I know, these are just workarounds (though I forgot to make the first letter normalsize). If you really want it, you can (a) write a mathjax-compatible TeX command [its's easy to import these to chem.se, though I dunno if the devs will do it for an apparently not-so-useful command] that renders as textsc (b) [submit a feature-request](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues?state=open), or (c) write a mathjax extension

Answer (score 4):

*(The question has currently no tag indicating it is MathJax/Tex/.. related, so let me be more general...)*

Smallcaps support in general SE syntax, not (only) in MathJax, is **essential** for correct typesetting of the **D/L-** stereochemical prefixes (e.g. in β-D-glucopyranose or L-alanine).<sup>*</sup>

Citing from the [ACS style guide – Conventions in chemistry](https://doi.org/10.1021/bk-2006-STYG.ch013):

> Use small capital letters D and L for absolute configuration with amino acids and carbohydrates.<sup>*</sup>

or from the [Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry: IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013](https://doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069):

> **P-102.3.2** The stereodescriptors ‘D’ and ‘L’ <sup>*</sup>
>
> (…) The configurational stereodescriptors ‘D’ and ‘L’ must be written in small capital letters and linked by a hyphen to the name of a sugar.<sup>*</sup>
>   (…)

There's a feature request in meta.SE to [allow the <small> tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40035/148486), which is a usual realization of this typography e.g. at the Wikipedia.

Another possible solution is to use Unicode small capital letters (preview: β-ᴅ-glucopyranose or ʟ-alanine), however these are meant to have IPA/phonetic meaning.

---

*) *The D/L notation is here incorrectly presented in capital letters, because of missing smallcaps support*

Comment: Experiments [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4308/544).

Answer (score 3):

For me, the answer is clearly that **we don't really need small caps**. Small caps for author names are a convention in some publications, but there is no need for us to adopt it. In particular, it's not a common convention in chemistry journals…

Comment: maybe we don't need them in formulae, bot we do in some names, so I [don't agree](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4274/544)