# Good idea(?) for editing meta post: "How can I format math/chemistry expressions here?"

Tags: discussion

I want to edit the meta post [How can I format math/chemistry expressions here?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/22102) to make the page easier to navigate.

My suggestion would be to take the large [answer](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/88/22102) and break it into multiple answers such as

- Getting started
- Basic chem
- Basic math: Superscripts and subscripts
- Basic math: Fractions and square roots

and so on.

Then add the above list to the question itself as an index. Each of the list items would be linked to the corresponding answer.

Is this OK with everyone?

Comment: I have no objections.

Comment: When breaking up the content into multiple structured answers, we could handle even more information. We might want to check the various scattered related meta posts if they could be included in this post, too – for example, the [italics and uprights](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/444/7951) topic. Or at least include suitable links to such posts.

Comment: I favor the idea of having the most commonly used examples right in the first page, and then going into detail. I think that would accommodate folks who have not done any formatting at all, and want to submit their question. Something like https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4718/72973. That personal preference aside, I think it is a great idea.

Comment: @user2362 - Yes, my notion was next to pull in some additional information from other posts. If possible I'd like to move all the stuff on one page so that the reader can bounce around without getting lost.

Comment: Note that `mhchem` usage is already covered pretty well in [the official manual](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/), and there is an extremely extensive math coverage in [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Tips on fine-tuning, non-obvious examples as well as various chemistry-related hacks are posted in [the sandbox](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3077/formatting-sandbox-ii-please-test-stuff-here).

Comment: @andselisk - I shouldn't have been so inclusive when I talked about moving "all the stuff on one page." Obviously it would be crazy to try to redo the whole MathJax or mhchem manuals. The whole webpage needs to load  reasonably quickly. // I've looked at the sandboxes  at lot. There are a few very useful things there and a lot of wild stuff that would almost never be used. // The main idea though would be to give a new user one starting point that should cover most of what they need. Also point to where they can find more detailed information.

Comment: We need to be careful with what we want to accomplish here. If the initial landing page is heavy on MathJax, it takes a long time to load. Anew user might get frustrated at this. So keeping a short and simple landing page will have its benefits.

Comment: Just in case you have not checked the responses to your flags: It's is not possible to remove deleted posts entirely. They won't be shown to users with less than 10k reputation though. The best we can do is to reduce them to one line.